# SQL Server trigger conflict with reference table after delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I created a trigger which creates a new row with a new `ID` after a change. When I use the trigger with one table it works but when I use it on a table which has reference to another table, I am getting an error:

> DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint.

The tables look like this:

**Table1**:

```
ID       BEZEICHNUNG        MENGENEINHEIT        PREIS  .....
1        Harry Potter       Book                 20
2        iPod               Music                150
```

**Table2**:

```
DIENSTLEISTUNG_ID      RAUM_ID 
1                      2
2                      1
```

**Table 3**:

```
ID      Raumname ....
1       Elbe
2       Main
```

My trigger looks like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DIENSTLEISTUNG_Update]
   ON [dbo].[DIENSTLEISTUNG]
   AFTER  UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
 SET  NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @MAX_ID INT;
    SELECT @MAX_ID=MAX(ID) FROM [DIENSTLEISTUNG];

    declare @tmp Table(ID  numeric, BEZEICHNUNG nvarchar(64), MENGENEINHEIT nvarchar(64), 
    PREIS numeric(19,5), BESCHREIBUNG nvarchar(64), VORLAUFZEIT numeric(10),
    AZ_MO nvarchar(22), AZ_DI nvarchar(22),AZ_MI nvarchar(22),AZ_DO nvarchar(22),AZ_FR nvarchar(22),
    AZ_SA nvarchar(22),AZ_SO nvarchar(22),DIENSTLEISTUNGSART_ID numeric(38),
    UPDATE_USER numeric(38), UPDATE_DATE datetime, RUESTZEIT numeric(38),
    PERMISSIONS numeric (38), KONTRAKTPOSITION numeric(38),ARTIKELNUMMER nvarchar(64),
    ANZAHL numeric(10), BUCHUNGSHINWEIS nvarchar(255), SONDERWUNSCH char(1),
    FLAG bit)

    insert into @tmp
    select
    ID, BEZEICHNUNG, MENGENEINHEIT, 
    PREIS, BESCHREIBUNG, VORLAUFZEIT,
    AZ_MO, AZ_DI,AZ_MI,AZ_DO,AZ_FR,
    AZ_SA,AZ_SO,DIENSTLEISTUNGSART_ID,
    UPDATE_USER, UPDATE_DATE, RUESTZEIT,
    PERMISSIONS, KONTRAKTPOSITION,ARTIKELNUMMER,
    ANZAHL, BUCHUNGSHINWEIS, SONDERWUNSCH,
    1 [flag] from deleted;


    delete T from DIENSTLEISTUNG T JOIN @tmp I
    ON T.ID=I.ID

SET IDENTITY_INSERT   [DIENSTLEISTUNG] ON
INSERT INTO [DIENSTLEISTUNG] (ID, BEZEICHNUNG, MENGENEINHEIT, 
    PREIS, BESCHREIBUNG, VORLAUFZEIT,
    AZ_MO, AZ_DI,AZ_MI,AZ_DO,AZ_FR,
    AZ_SA,AZ_SO,DIENSTLEISTUNGSART_ID,
    UPDATE_USER, UPDATE_DATE, RUESTZEIT,
    PERMISSIONS, KONTRAKTPOSITION,ARTIKELNUMMER,
    ANZAHL, BUCHUNGSHINWEIS, SONDERWUNSCH,
    FLAG)
SELECT @MAX_ID+ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) [ID],BEZEICHNUNG, MENGENEINHEIT, 
    PREIS, BESCHREIBUNG, VORLAUFZEIT,
    AZ_MO, AZ_DI,AZ_MI,AZ_DO,AZ_FR,
    AZ_SA,AZ_SO,DIENSTLEISTUNGSART_ID,
    UPDATE_USER,GETDATE(),RUESTZEIT,
    PERMISSIONS, KONTRAKTPOSITION,ARTIKELNUMMER,
    ANZAHL, BUCHUNGSHINWEIS, SONDERWUNSCH,
    0 
FROM INSERTED
union all
select * from @tmp

 SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.DIENSTLEISTUNG OFF
 SET  NOCOUNT OFF;
END;
```

Comment: Simple enough: you're trying to delete something that is still being referenced by rows. This is the whole point of having referential integrity (foreign keys) - you shouldn't be doing this! Figure out what you're trying to delete, and what other rows still refer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is occurring is because although you are re-inserting a row with the same ID, at the time when you are deleting the row SQL has no way of knowing you are going to re-insert it to maintain the referential integrity.

It appears the purpose of this trigger is to not allow updates, and insert a new row whenever a change is made, so I think an `INSTEAD OF` trigger will be more suited to your needs. You can then just ignore any changes made to the existing row, and insert the new row, avoiding any deletions so avoiding any referencial integrity problems.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DIENSTLEISTUNG_Update]
   ON [dbo].[DIENSTLEISTUNG]
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [DIENSTLEISTUNG] (BEZEICHNUNG, MENGENEINHEIT, 
        PREIS, BESCHREIBUNG, VORLAUFZEIT,
        AZ_MO, AZ_DI,AZ_MI,AZ_DO,AZ_FR,
        AZ_SA,AZ_SO,DIENSTLEISTUNGSART_ID,
        UPDATE_USER, UPDATE_DATE, RUESTZEIT,
        PERMISSIONS, KONTRAKTPOSITION,ARTIKELNUMMER,
        ANZAHL, BUCHUNGSHINWEIS, SONDERWUNSCH,
        FLAG)
    SELECT  BEZEICHNUNG, MENGENEINHEIT, 
        PREIS, BESCHREIBUNG, VORLAUFZEIT,
        AZ_MO, AZ_DI,AZ_MI,AZ_DO,AZ_FR,
        AZ_SA,AZ_SO,DIENSTLEISTUNGSART_ID,
        UPDATE_USER,GETDATE(),RUESTZEIT,
        PERMISSIONS, KONTRAKTPOSITION,ARTIKELNUMMER,
        ANZAHL, BUCHUNGSHINWEIS, SONDERWUNSCH,
        0 
    FROM INSERTED

    UPDATE  DIENSTLEISTUNG
    SET     Flag = 1 
    FROM    DIENSTLEISTUNG 
            INNER JOIN INSERTED
                ON INSERTED.ID = DIENSTLEISTUNG.ID

END
```

Comment: thank you, but how can i set the edited row a flag with the value 1 after the change